# refreshing already placed MS Visio shapes after editing the master shape

Tags: microsoft-visio

We use to draw network topologies and also use our own shapes. These shapes are saved as a master shape in a template.

So for our orjects we place every shape multiple times on the desk.
Now, if there is any change to the master shape, we need to delete and add every shape on the desk again.

Is it possible to refresh all already placed shapes if the master shape is changed?

If MS Visio can't do it, is there any other programm?

Comment: Which Visio version do you use ?

Comment: I have access to every version. So anyone that supports this feature

Answer (score 1):

Try use **Change shape** command (added in Visio 2013) [image]
0. Activate stencil which contain new masters
1. Select shape which you need replace in you diagram
2. Click on **Change shape** command
3. Select new master-shape which you want use rather than old selected shape
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This I old and if you found an answer please post.

I am looking at his problem right now and I have found out that the Master Shape in the stencils do NOT Update the shapes (and probably will never) just as you have mentioned.

However in the Document Stencil where all the masters you used in the document (Masters that are still used (still linked) and others used in the past) are kept. If you edit THOSE masters, all the shapes linked to that master will UPDATE.